# Android GameHelper without BaseGameActivity

Tags: android, leaderboard

I want to implement google leaderboards in my game. Google says that i need to use BaseGameActivity but I am using AndEngine and its not based on the same BaseGameActivity.

At googles website its written that if i do not use BaseGameActivity i should use GameHelper.

```
mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
```

But GameHelper class is not resolved. Do you know which library i should implement and how should i implement to get the GameHelper class working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

The integration is explained here.
First you need to import it as a project inside eclipse and then add it to your project as a library.

It also contains the GameHelper class.
if you dont want to use BaseActivity, you can just check out BaseActivity source code and add relevant code to your own activity.
It basically initializes the GameHelper object in `onCreate` and call its lifecycle methods in  `onStart` `onPause` etc.

Google itself has guide for it as a separate section here
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#using_gamehelper_without_basegameactivity

Comment: I now both links. thats actually where i found the code that i attached. But i am not using eclipse. I am using androidStudio. So i need a jar file right?

Comment: here it is explained how to run both in eclipse and android studio https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples

Comment: info for that is here https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: I will do it as soon as i solve the problem... Google play services are already imported to my project. But i still can not import GoogleAPIClient nor GameHelper

Comment: can you try running the samples. what error they give ?

Comment: I am still trying to import them to android studio... What should i give as Gradle Home during importing?

Comment: i wont be able to help with that as i use Eclipse

Comment: Problem solved: that was missing
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                   android:value="348611467344" />